# Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' on ec2

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, python-2.7, amazon-ec2

I was using mysql on amazon ec2 instance.I pushed about 1000 records into my database table
and then ran a multithreaded python script which picks records and updates them.Each time
I inserted 1000 ecords ran the script and after the script was done I deleted those 1000 records and again repeated the same(to see how much time it was taking).It worked for the first two time but the the third time I got this:
`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'`.What could be the reason for that??
here is what my log file looks like:

```
   30702 16:02:36 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
   130702 16:02:36 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
   130702 16:02:36 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
   130702 16:02:36 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
   130702 16:02:36 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M

   InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
   130702 16:02:36 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
   130702 16:02:36 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
   130702 16:02:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
   130702 16:02:36 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
   130702 16:02:36 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
   130702 16:02:36 [ERROR] Aborting

   130702 16:02:36 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

   130702 16:02:37 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
   130702 16:02:37 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
   130702 16:02:37 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
   130702 16:02:37 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
   130702 16:02:37 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
   InnoDB: mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
   130702 16:02:37 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
   130702 16:02:37 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
   130702 16:02:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
   130702 16:02:37 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
   130702 16:02:37 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
   130702 16:02:37 [ERROR] Aborting

   130702 16:02:37 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Here is the space info on my instance:

```
Filesystem Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  1.8G  5.8G  23% /
udev            288M  8.0K  288M   1% /dev
tmpfs           119M  180K  118M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            296M     0  296M   0% /run/shm
```

And here is my my.cnf configration file:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quote

# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock    # Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Looks like `mysqld` died. Try to restart it and look into the mysql error logs (Probably in `/var/log/mysql`).

Comment: @RedBaron I have edited to include my error.log

Comment: I think you have run out of disk space. `df -h` will show free space. Look specifically for space on the partition on which `/var/` is mounted.

Comment: for those having the same problem: My mysql buffer wanted 128M but could not find it thus it was stopped.Then restarting it had problems could not get around it so again installed mysql server.AWS instance has very less RAM,thus buffer pool could not be allocated.You can read about swap space(to increase RAM,slow but is of use )